# How to find and replace (or append) text to a text area

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to replace a website url (`@user.website`) that is contained in a text area (`#mention`) with a shortened url when clicked. It must only perform the swap if the website(`@user.website`) is actually present in the text area otherwise it must append the short url to the end of the text area.

```
$(function(){
  $(".short_url_link").click(function(){
  var mention = $("#mention");
  var previousText = mention.text();
  if (previousText.indexOf("<%= @user.website %>") >= 0) {
     var shortURL = $(this).text();
     var regex = new RegExp(("<%= @user.website %>").replace(/\//g, "\\/").replace(/\./g, '\\.'), "i");
     mention.val(previousText.replace(regex, shortURL));
   } else {
     mention.val( mention.val() + ' ' + $(this).text() );
   }
 });
```

});

The function I have isn't quite right. It deletes everything after the newly added short url if the website url is in the middle of the text area. It's also not adding the correct text (seems to add previous selection) if the website url isn't present. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: just tried your code it works: http://jsfiddle.net/DWU47/2/

Comment: I set the value of the text area on page load (value='some text www.google.com some text'). Whenever I click the link this value is used for the replacement and not the current text in the text area (even if the text in the text area has changed)

Comment: textareas are not meant to use the `value=""` attribute, therefore when you use jQuery's `.val()` it won't extract that. if you need some place to store a string use something like `data-value=""` and retrieve it with `.data('value')`